# 403 Error - Unable to create Paragraphs via REST with ?_format=hal_json

Tags: security, paragraphs, 8

Trying to add paragraphs via REST to the earlier created node.

I've installed the *Paragraphs Type Permissions* module, enabled the following permissions for my REST user's role

- Text: Create content
- Video: Create content

*See:* https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3012600#comment-12851834

but still getting an error 403 and {"message":""} in response while trying to add some paragraphs to the node created earlier.

Error log:

```
Type        access denied
Date        Monday, December 28, 2020 - 20:40
User        restadmin
Location    https://drupal-8.site/entity/paragraph?_format=hal_json
Referrer    
Message     Path: /entity/paragraph?_format=hal_json. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException: in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 120 of /var/www/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).
Severity    Warning
Hostname    77.139.170.139
Operations
```

Here JSON for the Text Paragraph:

```json
   {
        "field_text": [
            {
                "value": text,
                "format": "full_html",
                "processed": text
            }
        ],
        "parent_id": [
            {
                "value": str(parent_id)
            }
        ],
        "parent_type": [
            {
                "value": "node"
            }
        ],
        "parent_field_name": [
            {
                "value": "field_paragraphs"
            }
        ],
        "type": [
            {
                "target_id": "text"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": base_url + REST_TYPE_PARAGRAPH_TEXT
            }
        }
    }
```

Here JSON for the Video paragraph:

```json
{
        "field_video": {
            "value": "video:" + str(video_id)
        },
        "parent_id": [
            {
                "value": str(parent_id)
            }
        ],
        "parent_type": [
            {
                "value": "node"
            }
        ],
        "parent_field_name": [
            {
                "value": "field_paragraphs"
            }
        ],
        "type": [
            {
                "target_id": "video"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": base_url + REST_TYPE_PARAGRAPH_VIDEO
            }
        }
    }
```

What permission am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Check on permission **Paragraphs Type Permissions -> Bypass Paragraphs type content access control** was missing here.

There was also a problem with the JSON request payload of the video paragraph, here the correct version:

```json
    {
        "field_video": [
            {
                "target_id": video_id
            }
        ],
        "parent_id": [
            {
                "value": parent_id
            }
        ],
        "parent_type": [
            {
                "value": "node"
            }
        ],
        "parent_field_name": [
            {
                "value": "field_paragraphs"
            }
        ],
        "type": [
            {
                "target_id": "video"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": base_url + REST_TYPE_PARAGRAPH_VIDEO
            },
            base_url +  REST_RELATION_PARAGRAPH_VIDEO_FIELD_VIDEO: [
                {
                    "href": base_url + "/media/%d/edit" % video_id + FORMAT_HAL_JSON,
                    "lang": "en"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

And a correct/working version of the text paragraph JSON payload:

```json
    {
        "field_text": [
            {
                "value": text,
                #"format": "full_html" - getting error "full_html" not recognized
            }
        ],
        "parent_id": [
            {
                "value": str(parent_id)
            }
        ],
        "parent_type": [
            {
                "value": "node"
            }
        ],
        "parent_field_name": [
            {
                "value": "field_paragraphs"
            }
        ],
        "type": [
            {
                "target_id": "text"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": base_url + REST_TYPE_PARAGRAPH_TEXT
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After fixing those issues and passing a successful (status: 200) update (patch) to the node, I still cant see those paragraphs in the node. What I'm missing here?